# Boto3 uses old credentials

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, tkinter, boto3

I am using `tkinter` to create gui application that returns the security groups. Currently if you want to change your credentials (e.g. if you accidentally entered the wrong ones) you would have to restart the application otherwise `boto3` would carry on using the old credentials.

I'm not sure why it keeps using the old credentials because I am running everything again using the currently entered credentials.

This is a snippet of the code that sets the environment variables and launches `boto3`. It works perfectly fine if you enter the right credentials the first time.

```
os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = self.accessKey
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = self.secretKey

self.sts_client = boto3.client('sts')

self.assumedRoleObject = self.sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn=self.role,
    RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession1"
)

self.credentials = self.assumedRoleObject['Credentials']

self.ec2 = boto3.resource(
    'ec2',
    region_name=self.region,
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'],
)
```

The credentials variables are set using:

```
self.accessKey = str(self.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_Form.get())
self.secretKey = str(self.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_Form.get())
self.role = str(self.AWS_ROLE_ARN_Form.get())
self.region = str(self.AWS_REGION_Form.get())
self.instanceID = str(self.AWS_INSTANCE_ID_Form.get())
```

Is there a way to use different credentials in `boto3` without restarting the program?

Comment: This is wrong way to assign a mutable access for boto3 module.  Because boto API will assume and use the cached access key   @Vor answer is the explicit way to tell the boto .

Comment: @mootmoot If I reload the module using `importlib.reload` it should 'clear' the cache right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need boto3.session.Session to overwrite the access credentials.

Just do this 
reference http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/session.html

```
import boto3

# Assign you own access 
mysession = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id='foo1', aws_secret_access_key='bar1')

# If you want to use different profile call foobar inside .aws/credentials
mysession = boto3.session.Session(profile_name="fooboar")

# Afterwards, just declare your AWS client/resource services    
sqs_resource=mysession.resource("sqs")

# or client 
s3_client=mysession.client("s3")
```

Basically, little change to your code. you just pass in the session instead of direct boto3.client/boto3.resource

```
self.sts_client = mysession.client('sts')
```

Answer (score 6):

Sure, just create different `sessions` from  `botocore.session.Session` object for each set of credentials:

```
import boto3
s1 = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id='foo1', aws_secret_access_key='bar1')
s2 = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id='foo2', aws_secret_access_key='bar2')
```

Also you can leverage `set_credentials` method to keep 1 session an change creds on the fly:

```
import botocore
session - botocore.session.Session()

session.set_credentials('foo', 'bar')
client = session.create_client('s3')
client._request_signer._credentials.access_key
u'foo'

session.set_credentials('foo1', 'bar')
client = session.create_client('s3')
client._request_signer._credentials.access_key
u'foo1'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is this to set up multiple sessions at once? I would like to only have 1 session and terminate the old session if possible.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to implement this as I am not sure where the `role` will be set. Also, would this work with my current code or would I have to rewrite the `self.ec2 = boto3.resource` part of my code?

Comment: New code example after the boto3.session.Session example should clarify your issue.  e.g. s1_s3 = s1.resource("s3")

Answer (score 3):

The answers given by @mootmoot and @Vor clearly state the way of dealing with multiple credentials using a session.

@Vor's answer

```
import boto3
s1 = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id='foo1', aws_secret_access_key='bar1')
s2 = boto3.session.Session(aws_access_key_id='foo2', aws_secret_access_key='bar2')
```

---

But some of you would be curious about
**why does the boto3 client or resource behave in that manner in the first place?**

Let's clear out a few points about Session and Client as they'll actually lead us to the answer to the aforementioned question.

**Session**

- A 'Session' stores configuration state and allows you to create service clients and resources

**Client**

- if the credentials are not passed explicitly as arguments to the `boto3.client` method, then the credentials configured for the session will automatically be used. You only need to provide credentials as arguments if you want to override the credentials used for this specific client

Now let's get to the code and see what actually happens when you call `boto3.client()`

```
def client(*args, **kwargs):
    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)

def _get_default_session():
    if DEFAULT_SESSION is None:
        setup_default_session()
    return DEFAULT_SESSION

def setup_default_session(**kwargs):
    DEFAULT_SESSION = Session(**kwargs)
```

**Learnings from the above**

1. The function `boto3.client()` is really just a proxy for the boto3.Session.client() method
2. If you once use the client, the `DEFAULT_SESSION` is set up and for the next consecutive creation of clients it'll keep using the `DEFAULT_SESSION`
3. The credentials configured for the `DEFAULT_SESSION` are used if the credentials are not explicitly passed as arguments while creating the boto3 client.

**Answer**

- The first call to `boto3.client()` sets up the `DEFAULT_SESSION` and configures the session with the `oldCredsAccessKey`, `oldCredsSecretKey`, the already set values for env variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACESS_KEY` respectively.
- So even if you set new values of credentials in the environment, i.e do this

```
os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = newCredsAccessKey
os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = newCredsSecretKey
```

- **The upcoming `boto3.client()` calls still pick up the old credentials configured for the `DEFAULT_SESSION`**

**NOTE**

- `boto3.client()` call in this whole answer means that no arguments passed to the client method.

**References**

- https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3.html#client
- https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/session.html#Session
- https://ben11kehoe.medium.com/boto3-sessions-and-why-you-should-use-them-9b094eb5ca8e