# Python Boto3: Error when trying to download files from AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Helllo,

I am trying to download all the files from a S3 bucket that is extremely large. I am connecting to the S3 like this:

```
client = boto3.client('s3', 
aws_access_key_id=tempCredentials.credentials.access_key,
aws_secret_access_key = tempCredentials.credentials.secret_key,                                 
aws_session_token=tempCredentials.credentials.session_token)
```

From this, I do:

```
# This is going to go through and fill in the dictionary with keys 
from the buckets as specified above 
paginator = client.get_paginator("list_objects")
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket["Name"])
l = 0
# We are going to have an list that will hold all the keys 
key_list = []
for i in page_iterator:
    c = i["Contents"]
    for j in c:
          key_list.append(j["Key"])
    for j in key_list:
        download(bucket["Name"], j, "/Users/ahussain/Desktop/S3_Scrubber/" + file_name_helper(j), client)
```

Where, my download function as:

```
 def download (bucket_name, key, path, client):
    key_name = key 
    print("Dowloading %s..." % str(key))
    client.download_file(bucket_name, key, path)
    print("Download of %s complete!" % str(key))
    return key_name
```

What happens is that I go through the bucket successfully and download a good amount of keys, but after a while the program stops downloading keys and gives me this error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request
```

My guess is that my session expired since I am using an MFA to access this S3, but I am unsure. Has anyone ever run into this error before?

Comment: When constructing the client, can you try specifying the region your bucket is in? `client = boto3.client('s3',region_name='us-west-1', ....`

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is either wrong or outdated. I'm not sure. You can increase how long your credentials last. They can last up to 12 hours. The maximum is not 1 hour. Go to IAM > Roles > Your specified role > Edit the session duration.

[image]

As per the [IAM documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html), the maximum is defined by the Maximum CLI/API session duration, the max of which is 12 hours.

Editing might fix your issue, considering your operation may take more than 1 hour and less than 12. If more than 12, consider editing your script to refresh credentials. To be honest, I'm not sure how to do this or if it is possible, but this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894947/boto3-uses-old-credentials) might help, as well as the [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

Temporary credentials are only valid for up to one hour. From the [IAM documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html):

> The duration, which specifies how long the temporary security credentials are valid. The minimum is 15 minutes (900 seconds) and the maximum (and the default) is 1 hour (3600 seconds). You need to pass this value only if you want the temporary credentials to expire before 1 hour.

According to an open bug (https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/443) `boto3` doesn't support refreshing of temporary credentials for long running operations.

So if your script shows that error after ~1 hour that's likely the reason.