# How to specify credentials when connecting to boto3 S3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

On boto I used to specify my credentials when connecting to S3 in such a way:

```
import boto
from boto.s3.connection import Key, S3Connection
S3 = S3Connection( settings.AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY, settings.AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY )
```

I could then use S3 to perform my operations (in my case deleting an object from a bucket).

With boto3 all the examples I found are such:

```
import boto3
S3 = boto3.resource( 's3' )
S3.Object( bucket_name, key_name ).delete()
```

I couldn't specify my credentials and thus all attempts fail with `InvalidAccessKeyId` error.

How can I specify credentials with boto3?

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36913771/2681632

Comment: See the "Configuring Credentials" section in the official documentation: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html

Comment: I find it super strange to call this 'AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY'. The name is 'access key id' and has nothing to do with the public part of a keypair. Also an access to a service like s3 should not be confused with a server(host) access. And i recommend to not let this key id becoming public (even if it's useless alone)

Answer (score 347, accepted):

You can create a [session](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session):

```
import boto3
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY,
)
```

Then use that session to get an S3 resource:

```
s3 = session.resource('s3')
```

Comment: works, I will take it as the answer. Why on earth don't they document this as the obvious way to do it?!!

Comment: As mentioned in a comment above, this _is_ in fact in the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html).

Comment: @Moot I was initially going to say I couldn't find this in the docs but under [credentials](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html) in the 'warning' section it notes that the token is optional.  I don't really get why you would ever bother with that.

Comment: @JimmyJames this is getting off topic, but you can use AWS STS to generate temporary credentials (e.g. valid for one hour). In that case, the session token is required, it won't work if you omit it.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks, I appreciate the response.  Perhaps I'll create a new question because this still doesn't make sense to me.  If you could pass just a token, then sure but it seems the secret key is always required and it's the same key that can be used to get a token.

Comment: @JimmyJames the use case for STS is that you start with `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` which have limited permissions. They don't allow you access S3, but they do allow you to [assume a role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) which can access S3. You make the AWS STS call to assume the role, which returns an new  `aws_access_key_id`, `aws_secret_access_key` and `aws_session_token` combination (the key and access key are different from the originals). You then use these credentials to create a new session to access S3.

Comment: @Alasdair Thanks.  That the keys were also generated as part of that was what I was missing.  I don't see why a token alone couldn't be made to be good enough (e.g. concat the other keys to it) but that's not a practical issue.

Answer (score 176):

You can get a `client` with new session directly like below.

```
 s3_client = boto3.client('s3', 
                      aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY, 
                      aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY, 
                      region_name=REGION_NAME
                      )
```

Comment: This works for getting an s3 *client*, but the OP wanted an s3 *resource* instead.

Comment: I agree with @Alasdair. The docs don't show how to do anything with client, and neither do you, so I don't see how this answer is relevant.

Comment: I tried this but it gives me "Unable to locate credentials" error..I had previously removed ~/.aws folder to test this as i know that boto will by default look for creds there...

Comment: This is the right answer and the only method that works as today. I don't know what you guys are talking about this not being useful. You can do ANYTHING using the client and there's extensive documentation for EVERY AWS service. Just take a look for S3: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html

Comment: @Dan whilst Client is very useful, there are additional constraints over Resource.  For instance, Client can only receive info for 1000 objects at a time.

Comment: Client is better in some cases, e.g.: "The main benefit of using the Boto3 client are: It maps 1:1 with the actual AWS service API. All AWS service operations supported by clients" https://www.learnaws.org/2021/02/24/boto3-resource-client/

Comment: This works only if you have a credential file already in .aws folder with different access key and secret pairs for other purposes

Answer (score 18):

This is older but placing this here for my reference too. boto3.resource is just implementing the default Session, you can pass through boto3.resource session details.

```
Help on function resource in module boto3:

resource(*args, **kwargs)
    Create a resource service client by name using the default session.

    See :py:meth:`boto3.session.Session.resource`.
```

https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/86392b5ca26da57ce6a776365a52d3cab8487d60/boto3/session.py#L265

you can see that it just takes the same arguments as Boto3.Session

```
import boto3
S3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-west-2', aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SERVER_SECRET_KEY)
S3.Object( bucket_name, key_name ).delete()
```

Answer (score 14):

I'd like expand on @JustAGuy's answer. The method I prefer is to use `AWS CLI` to create a config file. The reason is, with the config file, the `CLI` or the `SDK` will automatically look for credentials in the `~/.aws` folder. And the good thing is that `AWS CLI` is written in python.

You can get cli from pypi if you don't have it already. Here are the steps to get cli set up from terminal

```
$> pip install awscli  #can add user flag 
$> aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [****************ABCD]:[enter your key here]
AWS Secret Access Key [****************xyz]:[enter your secret key here]
Default region name [us-west-2]:[enter your region here]
Default output format [None]:
```

After this you can access `boto` and any of the api without having to specify keys (unless you want to use a different credentials).

Comment: You can also specify the column you want to fill :

- `aws configure set aws_access_key_id [****************ABCD]`
- `aws configure set aws_secret_access_key [****************xyz]`

Answer (score 13):

If you rely on your `.aws/credentials` to store id and key for a user, it will be picked up automatically.

For instance

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev')
s3 = session.resource('s3')
```

This will pick up the *dev* profile (user) if your `credentials` file contains the following:

```
[dev]
aws_access_key_id = AAABBBCCCDDDEEEFFFGG
aws_secret_access_key = FooFooFoo
region=op-southeast-2
```

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous ways to store credentials while still using boto3.resource().
I'm using the AWS CLI method myself. It works perfectly.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html?fbclid=IwAR2LlrS4O2gYH6xAF4QDVIH2Q2tzfF_VZ6loM3XfXsPAOR4qA-pX_qAILys

Answer (score 1):

Adding this code snippet, which makes it easy to work with multiple profiles defined in `~/.aws/config`:

```py
import boto3


class AwsAccount:
    account_id: str
    session: boto3.Session
    user_arn: str
    user_id: str

    def __init__(self, account_id: str, session: boto3.Session, user_arn: str, user_id: str):
        self.account_id = account_id
        self.session = session
        self.user_arn = user_arn
        self.user_id = user_id

    @staticmethod
    def from_profile_name(profile_name: str):
        session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile_name)
        identity = session.client('sts').get_caller_identity()

        return AwsAccount(
            account_id=identity['Account'],
            session=session,
            user_arn=identity['Arn'],
            user_id=identity['UserId'],
        )
```

Example usage:

```py
default_account = AwsAccount.from_profile_name('default')
another_account = AwsAccount.from_profile_name('other')

s3 = default_account.session.client('s3')
s3.delete_object(Bucket='string', Key='string')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set default aws env variables for secret and access keys - that way you dont need to change default client creation code - though it is better to pass it as a parameter if you have non-default creds

Answer (score 0):

1. Use your aws configured profile

   ```
   session = boto3.Session(profile_name='demo-account')
   ec2 = session.resource('ec2')
   ```
2. Set AWS_PROFILE Environment Variable, boto3 use the profile mentioned in this variable.

   **Windows:**

   ```
   set AWS_PROFILE=demo-account
   ```

   **Linux/MacOS:**

   ```
   export AWS_PROFILE=demo-account
   ```
3. Use keys in Code (Not Recommended):

   Embed keys in the code directly,its not the recommended way to access aws resources with boto3.

   s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='ACCESS_KEY',
   aws_secret_access_key='SECRET_KEY',region_name=REGION_NAME)