# boto3 ec2 & django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'M new using django and python, i try to use aws ec2 API to create, start and stop instances in aws ec2: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#instance

I found boto3 and i think that's the solution, but i don't know how to install in django framework i try using this in a view:

```
import boto3 #import directly

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
```

I think it's works but i receive the message:

> botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.

According to boto docs i need to set my api keys and the region: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html, but where i put this data in django?

For me this is not the best solution because I don't use INSTALLED_APPS in settings, is there a django package or a better solution to do?

Comment: Just put the data inside this `~/.aws/config` file. Boto3 automatically loads the config from the above mentioned file. there was nothing to do with django. put apikey and secret inside `~/.aws/credentials` file

Comment: @AvinashRaj Is there another way to set the apikey, like in python class?

Comment: Take a look at this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981950/how-to-specify-credentials-when-connecting-to-boto3-s3

Comment: Thanks a lot, excuse me for this stupid question, but i'm new in python world