# No Credentials Error: Trying to load files from aws s3 bucket into jupyter notebook

Tags: python, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook

I am working with python and jupyter notebook and am getting a 'No credentials' error when using the following code:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
```

I have awscli installed into my notebook with:

```
pip install awscli --user
```

I have also tried adding:

```
aws configure
```

but that gave me a syntax error. I also have aws cli installed in my laptop, even though I am working in a jupyter notebook. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify credentials when connecting to boto3 S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981950/how-to-specify-credentials-when-connecting-to-boto3-s3)

Answer (score 3):

You can set credentials with the following commands:

```
!aws configure set aws_access_key_id $ID
!aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $KEY
!aws configure set default.region $REGION
```