# Can I get an S3 resource from a client object in Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

In many AWS programs (not don't use S3), I have the following:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='myname')
awsclient = session.client(service_name='s3', region_name='us-east-2', use_ssl=True)
```

Most examples of S3 resource look like this:

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')  # high-level interface
```

Is there a way I can get the resource from the awsclient variable above, after establishing my profile and region? Or alternatively, how can I specify the profile name on an S3 Resource?

My goal is to have some consistency from one program to the other in how we connect and specify region/credentials.

This partially answers:
[How to specify credentials when connecting to boto3 S3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981950/how-to-specify-credentials-when-connecting-to-boto3-s3)
but doesn't address how to specify region.

Comment: Does [this](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.resource) help?

Comment: It helps, but doesn't show how to use client.  I would like to be able to have same code from one program to the other in regards to setting up user/region.  If AWS uses that for other services, why not use it on S3 service.

Comment: Just change `session.client()` to `session.resource()`: `s3_resouce = session.resource(service_name='s3', region_name='us-east-2', use_ssl=True)`